# mean variance relationship of the generalized Gamma

Tags: generalized-linear-model, gamma-distribution

The Gamma distribution has a mean-variance power relationship of
$$var(Y) = a \mu^2$$
where $a$ is a constant and $\mu$ is the mean.

Is this also the case for the generalized Gamma distribution?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_gamma_distribution

Comment: If $Y \sim \text{Gamma}(a,b)$, the mean $E[Y]=a b$ and $\text{Var}[Y] = a b^2$. I would not characterise this, as you have done, as a constant times $\mu^2$, when a constant times $\mu$ will suffice, and the constant is notably one of the parameters (which should be mentioned). [BTW, if you like power relationships, you could also write is as constant times $\mu^n$, for any integer $n$ ].

Answer (score 2):

The generalized gamma distribution is a three-parameter distribution, so you simple cannot expect to express the variance as a function of the mean.  The expressions for mean and variance in the linked wikipedia page is rather complex, so I will not try any algebra here.  But if you try to express the variance reexpressing one of the parameters using the mean, there will still be left one other free parameter. So for each value of the mean, there will be a two-parameter set of possible values for the variance, quite possibly this will be $(0, \infty)$. .